# Finding relative libraries when using symlinks to ruby executables

Tags: ruby, symlink

Imagine you have an executable foo.rb, with libraries bar.rb layed out in the following manner:

```
<root>/bin/foo.rb
<root>/lib/bar.rb
```

In the header of foo.rb you place the following require to bring in functionality in bar.rb:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__)+"../lib/bar.rb"
```

This works fine so long as all calls to foo.rb are direct.  If you put  as say $HOME/project, and symlink foo.rb into `$HOME/usr/bin`, then `__FILE__` resolves to `$HOME/usr/bin/foo.rb`, and is thus unable to locate `bar.rb` in relation to the dirname for `foo.rb`.

I realize that packaging systems such as rubygems fix this by creating a namespace to search for the library, and that it is also possible to adjust the load_path using `$:` to include `$HOME/project/lib`, but it seems as if a more simple solution should exist.  Has anyone had experience with this problem and found a useful solution or recipe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is ages old, but I just found this:

```
require 'pathname'
APP_ROOT = File.join(File.dirname(Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath),'..')
```

Comment: That's definitely better, at least it's just two lines.  Still unfortunate that there is not a single line solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to follow any symlinks and return the full path of the real file:

```
def follow_link(file)
  file = File.expand_path(file)

  while File.symlink?(file)
    file = File.expand_path(File.readlink(file), File.dirname(file))
  end

  file
end

puts follow_link(__FILE__)
```

Comment: I suppose that works.  Not really a happy solution for something that is supposed to be the first require in the file.  I'm not happy with a solution that include that snippet in every file in order to find our where it was called from.

Answer (score 1):

Probably worth mentioning that `+` works nicely with `Pathname` objects and also there is `Kernel.Pathname` method, so @Burke's original code could be made even shorter:

```
require 'pathname'
APP_ROOT = Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath + "../../lib"
```